Can Whitney's Embedding Theorem be generalized for spaces that locally look like an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R^n$?
Consider a topological space $M$ for which there is an $n$ such that every point $x\in M$ has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to some subset of $\mathbb R^n$. If we furthermore require $M$ to be Hausdorff and second-countable (and maybe paracompact too if it is not automatic in this case?), does it follow that $M$ embeds into $\mathbb R^k$ for some $k$?

Just a small remark: The Half-disc topology on $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q^{\ge 0}$ is Hausdorff, second-countable and locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$. Hence, indeed, "regular" needs to be added to the prerequisites of $M$ in order to get metrizability in @Moishe Kohan's nice answer (+1).

Yes. There are two steps for proving this. The first one is to prove that $M$ is metrizable and has covering dimension $\le n$. The second is a theorem that every separable metrizable space of covering dimension $n$ embeds in $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$. The book to read is chapter 1 of
Engelking, Ryszard, Dimension theory. A revised and enlarged translation of ”Teoria wymiaru”, Warszawa 1977, by the author, North-Holland Mathematical Library. Vol. 19. Amsterdam, Oxford, New York: North-Holland Publishing Company. Warszawa: PWN - Polish Scientific Publishers. X, 314p.  (1978). ZBL0401.54029.
For the 2nd step of the proof, see Theorem 1.11.4 in this book.
Edit. As Ulli correctly noted in their comment, one has to add the assumption that $M$ is regular. Then $M$ is metrizable by Urysohn's metrization theorem. One more thing: The space $M$ has dimension $\le n$ since it is a union of countably many open subsets of dimension $\le n$.
